# Writing a dask dataframe to parquet: 'TypeError'

Tags: python, dask, parquet

I am trying to use Dask to write parquet files. Target is to use its `repartition` feature, but it appears I am not able to write out a simple parquet file, without coming to the `repartition`step...

Here is the code I use to create a parquet file from pyarrow, read it back by dask, then write it again.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import dask.dataframe as dd

file = 'example.parquet'
file_res = 'example_res.parquet'

# Generate a random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(100000, 20)),columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T'])

# Write 1st parquet file with pyarrow
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, file, version='1.0')

# Read it back with Dask, and write it again
dd_df = dd.read_parquet(file)
dd_df.to_parquet(file_res)
```

The last writing step ends then with `TypeError: expected list of bytes`. Full log here below:

```sh
  File "C:/Users/me/Documents/code/_draft/pyarrow_parquet_store.py", line 31, in <module>
    dd_df.to_parquet(file_res)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 4075, in to_parquet
    return to_parquet(self, path, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\parquet\core.py", line 665, in to_parquet
    out = out.compute(**compute_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 279, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 567, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py", line 84, in get
    **kwargs

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 486, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 316, in reraise
    raise exc

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 222, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py", line 121, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\utils.py", line 30, in apply
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\parquet\fastparquet.py", line 625, in write_partition
    fil, df, fmd.schema, compression=compression, fmd=fmd

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py", line 631, in make_part_file
    rg = make_row_group(f, data, schema, compression=compression)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py", line 619, in make_row_group
    compression=comp)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py", line 513, in write_column
    data, selement)

  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py", line 254, in encode_plain
    return pack_byte_array(list(out))

  File "fastparquet\speedups.pyx", line 112, in fastparquet.speedups.pack_byte_array

TypeError: expected list of bytes
```

Thanks for any help. Bests.

Comment: Note that you seem to be implicitly using fastparquet - you can include `engine="pyarrow"` in read/to_parquet to keep to arrow.

Comment: weird, that was it it seems...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be the index: it is stored as pure metadata: `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=100000, step=1)`, but Dask infers this as having "object" (i.e., string or something more complex); hence the attempt to try to write the list of number as if they were strings.

Whilst this is a bug, here are some workarounds:

- don't write the index `dd_df.to_parquet(file_res, write_index=False)`
- for a single partition like this, the fastparquet API without dask work just fine
- drop the index or set a new index
- set the index dtype
- use pyarrow, `engine="pyarrow"`

Comment: Thanks @mdurant!   Yes, I switched to `pyarrow`. Do I need to report the bug, or are you a member of dask team?

Comment: I'll report it.